# Newtonsoft.Json [8.0.3, )' does not exist in project

Tags: xamarin

Although Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.0.0 is installed I get this error when try to add `Push Notification` nuget (which depends on Newtonsoft.Json >= 8.0.3)

Here is what I get:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2' with respect to project 'App.Main', targeting '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2'
Resolved actions to install package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2'
For adding package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2' to project 'App.Main' that targets 'portable45-net45+win8+wp8'.
For adding package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2' to project 'App.Main' that targets 'portable45-net45+win8+wp8'.
Adding package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2' to folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages'
Added package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2' to folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages'
Removed reference 'PushNotification.Plugin.Abstractions' from project 'App.Main'.
Added reference 'PushNotification.Plugin.Abstractions' to project 'App.Main'.
Removed reference 'PushNotification.Plugin' from project 'App.Main'.
Added reference 'PushNotification.Plugin' to project 'App.Main'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2 : Newtonsoft.Json [8.0.3, )' does not exist in project 'App.Main'
Removing package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2 : Newtonsoft.Json [8.0.3, )' from folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages'
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/content/portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10/Helpers'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/lib/portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10+UAP10'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/content/portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/content/MonoAndroid10'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/content/Xamarin.iOS10'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/content/MonoTouch10'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/lib/MonoAndroid10'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/lib/Xamarin.iOS10'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/lib/MonoTouch10'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/lib/UAP10'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/lib/wpa81'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/lib/win8'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/content'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2/lib'.
Removed file 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2.nupkg' from folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2'.
Removed folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages/Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2'.
Removed package 'Xam.Plugin.PushNotification.1.2.2 : Newtonsoft.Json [8.0.3, )' from folder '/Users/samir/Documents/projects/xamarin/packages'
Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The `.nuspec` for `Xam.Plugin.PushNotification` 1.2.2 includes:

```
<dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" />
```

Thus when it is resolving the dependencies `Newtonsoft.Json [8.0.3, )` it will fail if you have `Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.0` installed as that would be a breaking change since the **SemVer Major** version has changed.

http://docs.nuget.org/Create/Versioning

http://semver.org/spec/v1.0.0.html

Comment: I tried to delete the `Newtonsoft.Json` from project packages, then retried to install the `Xam.Plugin.PushNotification` but I got the same error, although `Newtonsoft.Json` version `8.0.3` has been installed